# Declaring implicit arguments in Coq: how many underscores are needed?

Tags: coq

In the following snippet of Coq code (cut down from a real example), I'm trying to declare the first argument to `exponent_valid` as implicit:

```coq
Require Import ZArith.
Open Scope Z.

Record float_format : Set := mk_float_format {
  minimum_exponent : Z
}.

Record float (fmt : float_format) : Set := mk_float {
  exponent : Z;
  exponent_valid : minimum_exponent fmt <= exponent
}.

Arguments exponent_valid {fmt} _.
```

As I understand it, the `exponent_valid` function takes two arguments: one of type `float_format` and one of type `float`, and the first can be inferred.  However, compiling the above snippet fails with the following error message:

```
File "/Users/mdickinson/Desktop/Coq/floats/bug.v", line 13, characters 0-33:
Error: The following arguments are not declared: _.
```

And indeed, changing the `Arguments` declaration to:

```coq
Arguments exponent_valid {fmt} _ _.
```

makes the error message go away.

That's okay; I'm a relative newcomer to Coq and I can well believe that I've overlooked something.  But now for the bit that's *really* confusing me: if I replace the `<=` in the definition of `exponent_valid` with a `<`, the code compiles without error!

I have two questions:

1. Why do I need an extra `_` in the first case ?
2. Why does replacing `<=` with `<` make a difference to the number of parameters expected by `exponent_valid` ?

In case it's relevant, I'm working with Coq 8.4pl5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`exponent_valid` has type

```coq
forall (fmt : float_format) (f : float fmt), minimum_exponent fmt <= exponent fmt f.
```

Without notations it's

```coq
forall (fmt : float_format) (f : float fmt), Z.le (minimum_exponent fmt) (exponent fmt f).
```

`Z.le` is defined as

```coq
= fun x y : Z => not (@eq comparison (Z.compare x y) Gt).
```

`not` is defined as

```coq
= fun A : Prop => A -> False.
```

And so `exponent_valid`'s type is convertible to

```coq
forall (fmt : float_format) (f : float fmt), 
   (minimum_exponent fmt ?= exponent fmt f) = Gt -> False,
```

which means the function can take upto three arguments.

But, I guess it's debatable whether the `Arguments` command should take convertibility into account or even if it needs to be supplied information on all arguments to a function. Maybe users should just be allowed to drop any trailing underscores.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation; that's helpful.  It would definitely be good to be able to drop trailing underscores.  As it stands, it seems that the coder either needs knowledge of all the definitions used, which breaks abstraction somewhat, or (s)he has to add underscores until the compiler stops complaining (and also has be aware that relatively simple changes could change the number of underscores needed).

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding is correct, and this looks like a (pretty weird) bug to me. I just filed a [report](https://coq.inria.fr/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=3946) on the bug tracker.

**Edit**: Ah, flockshade's observation below went by completely unnoticed while I was looking at this stuff. It does sense for it to have three arguments after all!

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and the report.  I'm afraid I'm changing the accepted answer;  sorry about that.